# In Strapi 4, how can I make a custom plugin route accessible to everyone?

Tags: strapi

I have a custom plugin that creates content-types. I want to be able to pull the created data for those content-types, I first try to access the basic, automatically created route in my plugin

GET /customplugin

But I get 401 unauthorized.

How can I make the route accessible for everyone? (No authorization needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/routes.html#public-routes

To a route object, just add inside the prop config, the prop auth with the value false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but in your routes array (I'm assuming you did write a plugin, so it is `./src/plugins/server/routes/index.js`) you can define a route like so:

```
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/my-custom-route',
    handler: 'controller-name.actionName',
    config: {
      auth: false,
      policies: [],
    },
  }
```

In the `config` section you can set `auth` to `false` and then no authentication is required for that route.

The explanation targets Strapi v4, i don't know if the route-structure has changed since then.

Maybe this helps (even a year later).